# How can I insert a divider in a b-dropdown after populating my dropdown using Vue?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuex

So to keep it simple, here is my code for my dropdown:

```
<b-dropdown id="SchemaDropdown"
                      name="SchemaDropdown"
                      variant="form-control"
                      class="" 
                      style="width: 100%"
                      v-on:change="changeItem">
                      <span slot=text>{{schemaName}}</span>
                    <b-dropdown-item v-for="option in schemas.Formats" 
                                      :key="option.mappingId" 
                                      :value="option.mapping"
                                      @click="changeItem(option.mappingId)">
                      {{option.mapping}}
                    </b-dropdown-item>
                    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
                  </b-dropdown>
```

My schemas object is basically a dictionary of available schemas and their related GUIDs. The dropdown works fine and selects schemas appropriately.

Now in the system, the first two schemas are default in the system, all the rest are customisations the user can pre-configure. So one customer may have 2 custom schemas, another may have 100. Who knows.

I'd like to have my b-dropdown-divider placed after the second schema so the dropdown looks like:

```
Default Schema 1
Default Schema 2
----------------
User Configured 1
User Configured 2
etc...
```

How can I insert the  at a specific point?

Comment: I don't know how vue works, but the divider is just an "<li class='divider'></li>" tag in twitter bootstrap, so can't you just insert it manually after the populating (maybe creating a model that only render a divider(?)) and insert that model after the b-dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed properties for this purpose:

```
  <b-dropdown-item 
      v-for="option in defaultOptions" 
     :key="option.mappingId" 
     :value="option.mapping"
     @click="changeItem(option.mappingId)">
     {{option.mapping}}
    </b-dropdown-item>

    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>

    <b-dropdown-item 
      v-for="option in customOptions" 
     :key="option.mappingId" 
     :value="option.mapping"
     @click="changeItem(option.mappingId)">
     {{option.mapping}}
    </b-dropdown-item>
```

And in javascript code:

```
    computed: {
      defaultOptions: function () {
        return this.schemas.Formats.slice(0, 2)
      },
      customOptions: function () {
        return this.schemas.Formats.slice(2, this.schemas.Formats.length)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your response, nice and easy solution!